# Rendering Vue HTML element inside jquery function

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, jsgrid

I was using jsGrid to display a server-side table and stuck with this problem where i want to use vue-color as a color picker on jsGrid editTemplate

[image: Import Vue Color]

[image: Initializing JsGrid Jquery]

[image: Rendering Vue JS Html element]

So i was wondering if there is anyway to render this chrome-picker element on the return statement of JsGrid editTemplate, as you guys can see in the image below, it didn't work

[image: not rendered]

i was hoping if you guys could help me on this problem, thanks

Comment: did you try Vue.compile? https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile

Comment: Please don't provide screenshots but actual code instead.

Comment: sorry about the screenshot, @ANRUpgradedVersion i just tried it, thanks, it was awesome, but im getting this error, http://prntscr.com/jsk73a . http://prntscr.com/jsk794, do you know why is it happening ?

Comment: @KawishBehzad it say _c is not defined , did you define it? what is _c here?

Comment: @ANRUpgradedVersion i tried to google it, _c is some kind of render variables lik e _h  for a component, apparently can't render the element from there, but luckily i found this https://codepen.io/Brownsugar/pen/NaGPKy, i think ill try to use that one, thanks for your help

Comment: Please do add the Solution  as Answer if you were able to continue , that may guide others in apt way @KawishBehzad